# capistrano 3. executables not found

Tags: capistrano

I have simple sinatra app for tests. Now i'm testing capistrano 3 and always get such error on my task `deploy:restart`:

```
bash: bundle: command not found
```

my Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

config/deploy.rb

```
set :application, 'captest'

set :repo_url, "https://iboltnev:password@bitbucket.org/iboltnev/simple-captest.git" 

set :deploy_to, '/home/ilya/capsinatra'
set :pty, true

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Start application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "bundle exec thin start -R app.rb"
    end 
  end 

end
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end
```

it seems like environment is different from my ssh-session, because i can start server with this shell command via ssh manually.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is an issue with your path, you need to check that your path is well set, run which bundle and paste the output here

Comment: `which bundle
cap aborted!
which bundle stdout: Nothing written
which bundle stderr: Nothing written`

Comment: ssh which bundle, or you add `which bundler` to the top of your Capfile

Comment: i added `execute "which bundle"` just before `execute "bundle exec thin start -R app.rb"` and got such result

Comment: I've repaired it by changing shell command to `source ~/.bash_profile && cd #{release_path} && bundle exec thin start`. But maybe there other more correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By your inclusion of `capistrano-rvm` I see you are using RVM.
But just including it does not make the RVM environment to be used by capistrano while deploying, as per the [`capistrano-rvm`](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/blob/master/README.md) documentation, you need to configure your stage environment with the RVM options needed:

#### config/deploy/staging.rb:

```rb
(...)
set :rvm_type, :user # or :auto
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p247@mygemset'
```

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: Did you change the ruby version and the gemset name to match the ones your project uses? And is the gemset installed on the server receiving the deploy?